# Use two fingers as ruler while drawing with Wacom tablet with touch feature

Tags: software-recommendation, osx, wacom

Is there any drawing software on macOS that let you use two fingers for showing a ruler while drawing with pen? Like the iOS 9 [Note](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0iHiMhjh00Y) app for iOS, for example.

Or when placing two fingers on two points, we get a angle at an axis, and no matter where we draw on the canvas it will always draw a straight line with that angle starting where the pen position is.

Not necessarily a native app, a web app would do as well, I want to draw straight lines quickly but does not have to be precisely accurate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Photoshop to draw a line easily. 
Create a new layer, select the Brush tool (or Pencil), left click on the first point of the line, hold Shift and left click again anywhere you want to finish the line.

Comment: but I wish to draw the stroke physically as well.

Answer (score 1):

iOS features are iOS features and not part of Photoshop. I don't know of any similar feature in any Adobe app. (Maybe it exists, I'm just an unaware.)

You **can** paint straight lines easily in Photoshop though, at any angle, but it's not angle-precise.....

- Grab a brush.
- Hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> down.
- Click once where you want the line to start...
- lift up (still depressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>)...
- click again where you want the line to stop.
- Let go of the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key.

  Photoshop will paint the brush in a straight line between the two points. This works for *any* painting tool in Photoshop.

If you need precise angles, you're better off with the pen tool and stroking paths manually. Or another app such as Illustrator.